# Icollection extraer un dato

Tags: c#

Tengo una colección que se llama:

```
usuario.Gerencias  que viene de (Icollection<Gerencia>)
```

La duda la tengo en que esto me muestra un listado de gerencias que dentro tiene varios datos.

Me gustaría poder extraer uno pasándole yo un `int`. Es decir se puede hacer algo parecido a :

```
usuario.Gerencias(idpasado) ???
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo debes de poner el nombre de tu variable, agregar corchetes y el indice que necesitas.

```
usuario.Gerencias[indice]
```

Pero estaría mejor que pusieras el código que manejas.